# What's the properties file equivalent property for the @Profile(!dev) annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In Spring-boot you can use the `@Profile(!dev)` annotation to exclude beans and classes from being provided when certain profiles are active or not active. Is there an equivalent property for this that can be used inside the application.yml?

Answer (score 1):

You can use @ConditionalOnProperty.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "stage", havingValue = "prod")
public NotificationSender notificationSender2() {
    return new SmsNotification();
}
```

Which will be disabled if you have `stage=dev` in your application properties.

There's blog from Eugen on it: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty

Comment: I was hoping there was an actual alternative and not a workaround since this is a different mechanism altogether. It's not clear I can replicate the same functionality either: the annotation I included as an example (`@Profile(!dev)`) would match all profiles that are *not* `dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use profile seperators in configuration file?

```
---
spring:
  profiles: dev

my-app.some-property: ...

---
spring:
  profiles: uat

my-app.some-property: ...
```

Or like GeertPt said in, you can use `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty` annotation to deal with your bean creation.

Even if you want you profile to be `dev`, you can use a feature flag to enable a bean. This might be helpful where you have to maintain multiple profiles.

For instance, I needed to log few properties on my stag server, but I was not willing to change in code base. So, with below, I only need to change the config-repo file and set the flag accordingly.

`my-app-dev.yml`

```
my-app:
  cloud:
    config:
      log-details: true
      log-ssl-properties: true
  swagger:
    enabled: false
```

`ConditionalConfigurationPropertiesLogger.java`

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
@Profile({"native", "dev"})
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my-app.cloud.config.log-details", havingValue = "true")
public class ConditionalConfigurationPropertiesLogger implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) {
    log.info(" <details> ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already using profile separators. I was hoping there was an actual alternative and not a workaround since this is a different mechanism altogether. It's not clear I can replicate the same functionality either: the annotation I included as an example (`@Profile(!dev)`) would match all profiles that are *not* `dev`.